# Help ctypes.windll.dnsapi.DnsQuery_A

Tags: python, winapi, dns, ctypes

I have trouble with [DnsQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016(VS.85).aspx) API, the *ppQueryResultsSet parameter troubles me. Can anyone show me an example of how to make correct DLL calls in python?

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
from windns_types import DNS_RECORD, IP4_ARRAY #declared here http://pastebin.com/f39d8b997


def DnsQuery(host, type, server, opt=0):
    server_arr = IP4_ARRAY()
    rr = DNS_RECORD()
    server_arr.AddrCount=1
    server_arr.AddrArray[0] = ctypes.windll.Ws2_32.inet_addr(server)
    ctypes.windll.dnsapi.DnsQuery_A(host, type, opt, server_arr, rr, 0)
    # WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000001

    return rr

print DnsQuery("www.google.com", 1, "208.67.222.222")
```

Comment: @ChristopheD,

I really want to, but looks like [lots of my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/41948/est) were not answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it a pointer to pointer to `DNS_RECORD`? This means you have to initialize rr as `POINTER(DNS_RECORD)()` and pass it by reference: `ctypes.byref(rr)`.

**Update**: But I think the problem you see is from passing `server_arr`: you pass a structure with first field being `0x00000001` instead of reference to this structure, so C code tries to dereference `AddrCount` field and gives you access violation. The same technique should be used for `server_arr` too.

Comment: Why it's `ctypes.POINTER(DNS_RECORD)()` not `ctypes.pointer(DNS_RECORD())` ? And look like still access violation reading 0x00000001

Comment: I the C world allocating a pointer to structure and allocation a structure and getting a pointer to it is not the same. While `ctypes.pointer(DNS_RECORD())` should work too, I'm not sure it's correct way.